# enzyme how to search for button inside render prop of route

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, render, enzyme

I am new to React and Enzyme and was writing test case for rendering of a button.
Can anyone please tell me how to search for a button inside render prop of Route?
This is my component:

```
            export default class App extends React.Component {
                render() {
                    return (
                        <div className='class1'>
                        .....
                            <Route id='Route-Home' render={({history}) => (
                                <Button id='Home-Button' onClick={() => {
                                    history.push(Constants.PATHS.HOME);
                                }}
                                text='Home' variant='emphasis'/>
                            )} />
                        .....
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
```

The closest I have come in my test case :

```
            describe('App', () => {
                let wrapper;
                beforeAll(()=>{
                    wrapper = shallow(<App />);
                }
                it('should render Home Button', () => {
                expect(wrapper.find('#Route-Home').prop('render').length).toBe(1);

                });

            });
```

Not able to find any working solution on how to test if the button is rendered. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Extract the function that you passed to the `render` prop of the Route and test it separately. Here is some sample code:

```
export const routeRenderFn = ({history}) => (
  <Button id='Home-Button' onClick={() => {
    history.push(Constants.PATHS.HOME);
  }}
  text='Home' variant='emphasis'/>
);

...

<Route id='Route-Home' render={routeRenderFn} />
```